# Mac OSX 10.6.8 - System settings through command line

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, mouse, touchpad

I would like to be able toggling the "Ignore embedded trackpad when a mouse or a trackpad is connected" in `System preferences > Universal access > Mouse and trackpad` from terminal, from the command line. Is that possible? Is there a reference document somewhere for accessing system preferences through command line?

Comment: ok, found some kind of answer here http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041215002018178 - basically there's a systemsetup command.

Comment: - apparently it does give access to only some settings, not the one i want. Well.